Records deleted from mysql database table
I have an application that can only insert entries to the database. When an existing record requires updating, the record is deleted and a new record created with new details.
The application worked fine for two years until a server crash a few months back, after which the records are randomly deleted from the table or are automatically approved for their statuses. These automatic approvals are not coming from the application because when approval is coming from the app, we capture the session username. These auto approved entries have null as session username.
Sometimes, a few entries goes missing randomly after few days. For example, a request for approval of seven line items are approved successfully, and after a month three lines go missing.
I have mostly worked with SQL Server and bigquery. This is my first experience with mysql. I could really use some inputs on where should I start looking for logs etc.
The db server is on gcloud inside a kubernetes container.

Have you checked the database integrity? If not, why not?

What Engine are the table(s)?  What version of MySQL?

What kind of application is this? If money is involved, you might also try to think about some attack by an hacker. It's always a bad idea to delete old data before the new data was created. Next time, create the new data first, check the new data and if the new data is okay, delete, or better, archive the old data.
